# 5V 4A power supply for simple circuit

Tags: arduino, power-supply, servo, 5v, robotics

I am a 14 year old electronics noob. I am mostly a programmer and mechanical designer. I have been working on a robot which needs around 4 amps of current. I am thinking about using a simple 5V 4A AC to DC adapter but they seem to be a pain to connect to a PCB. Especially since many mounts cannot even work with 4 Amps. I am trying to power 4 micro servos.

EDIT: How can I power this?

Edit 2: here is an image of my planned circuit:

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Edit 3: There is a slight error in the circuit diagram in servo 2: pin 2 of that is supposed to be connected to pin 6 of the Arduino.

Comment: Do you have a question or did you mistake this site for your diary?

Comment: oh shoot sorry!

Answer (score 1):

there are plenty of options...

don't know what your best dealer or online shop is, but for a PCBs things like that work perfectly:

https://www.reichelt.de/stecker-buchsen-c7538.html?&nbc=1

...

https://www.reichelt.de/leiterplattenklemmen-c7541.html?&nbc=1

you get em in all sizes, for all currents. Just search / ask for some good shops in your area of the world.

Maybe you even want such gernan called "Federzugklemme" (spring-type terminal) where the contact is achived with a stong metal spring. they have perfect contact. skrewed terminal might get loose by vibration. spring-type terminal are the better choice in that case

https://www.reichelt.de/federkraftklemme-steckbar-2-pol-rm-5-00-sp-02-5-vbpc-p159608.html?&trstct=pol_8&nbc=1

https://www.reichelt.de/federkraftklemme-3-pol-0-08-0-5-mm-rm-2-5-ast-021-03-p72167.html?&trstct=pol_12&nbc=1

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112539/discussion-on-answer-by-schnedan-5v-4a-power-supply-for-simple-circuit).

Answer (score 1):

If there's a way to split up your servo supplies, you could get away with two 5V/2A supplies, like for example fast-charge USB wall warts. That might be more compact than a typical off-the-shelf open-frame supply.

Comment: Thanks! That just might work as I have plenty of those. I have also been thinking I might only need 5v2a since I will never be stalling all servos (or even using) at once.